# Garageband—how to change volume of a region (not whole track)?

Tags: garageband

In garageband I have one audio track with many regions. I'd like to adjust the volume for each region. Is there an easy way to do that, or do I have to make a new track each time, and adjust the tracks volume?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally found the answer, not very intuitive but cool once you know.

There's a button to toggle 'automation'. Once that's on you can select from a dropdown whether you want to change volume, echo, reverb, etc. Then you click on the actual waves on the track and a coloured line will appear. Clicking along the line creates break points, and you can move either points or the line segments between points to shift the volume. It's not based on regions—you can adjust it anywhere.

For more information:
https://www.howtogeek.com/238649/how-to-use-automation-in-garageband/

Comment: Its interesting that the GarageBand iOS have something like Logic Pro called Clip Gain, but the MacOS version doesn't have.

Answer (score 11):

Under “Mix,” choose **Show Automation**. You didn’t have to do this before. Now you do.

Comment: how do you use it to amplify beyond the range of automation?

Comment: I also first had to add a software instrument before the menu item becaome enabled! After that, I could delete the software instrument track again, and automation stayed available.